# Form's client area not rendering size set in Form.ClientSize

Tags: c#, .net, size, dimensions

I've got a System.Windows.Forms.Form where I need to set the size of the client area at runtime. Strangely, though, even when I set the [ClientSize property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2.aspx) to 800x600, the area is smaller by 4 pixels on the right and bottom sides, which causes my content to be clipped by 4 pixels in both directions.

This behavior is observed with both the Windows XP and Windows Classic themes.

From my understanding of the MSDN documentation this should be doing what I want -- but it's not.

> The size of the client area of the
>   form is the size of the form excluding
>   the borders and the title bar.

Sample code here:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ClientSize = new Size(800, 600);
    }
}
```

What gives? I noticed in [the comments of an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603788/size-location-of-winforms-mdi-client-area/604275#604275) that this is happening to someone else. Is there any way I can set the size of the client area reliably?

Comment: I just tried that code (on VS2008, Win7) and it performs correctly without any extra pixels (measured on a screenshot). Perhaps the particular theme you use has invisible parts that are counted as borders?

Comment: Is there a max height and max width set on your form? Otherwise the size settings work pretty predictably.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both setting a max/min size as well as both the Windows XP and Windows Classic themes. I'm still seeing the form 4 pixels too small to the right and on the bottom. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was not with the Form at all. The form has a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control in it -- and that has a border. Since the WebBrowser control doesn't have any border property I didn't suspect it.