# Child Form Size Set to the MDI Form's MDI Container's Size

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

I'd like to know how I can have a child form load up with it's size covering the complete MDI Parent's MDI container space (the dark-gray thing)? Setting the child form's WindowState to Maximized is not an option as it'll maximize any other form too. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a solution to your problem, but I have to thank you for the aside about setting the WindowState.  That solved a problem I was having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this code should do it:

```
Form childForm = new Form();
f.Left = 0;
f.Top = 0;
f.Size = ParentForm.ClientRectangle.Size;
```

Comment: It's not opening up properly in the sense that the width and height is way to big. Here is the code I have tried so far and its not adjusting: `private void LoadDashboard() {
      Cursor saveCursor = Cursor.Current;
      try {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    Dashboard DisplayFormC = new Dashboard {
     MdiParent = this,
     Left = 0,
     Top = 0,
     Size = new Size(ClientRectangle.Size.Width - 200, ClientRectangle.Size.Height - 200)
    };

    DisplayFormC.Show();

      } finally {
        Cursor.Current = saveCursor;

      }     
    }`

Comment: Try the code laid out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603788/size-location-of-winforms-mdi-client-area

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/a315cefe-fe7f-4e23-b3e0-6cf614501ac2/
check the link the issue is resolved by inheriting the size

Answer (score 1):

I added a couple of lines to get it to fit inside the frame and it works well.

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.Left = 0;
childForm.Top = 0;
Rectangle recNew = new Rectangle();
recNew = ParentForm.ClientRectangle;
recNew.Height -= 4;
recNew.Width -= 4;
childForm .Size = recNew.Size;
```

I hope that helps!